# update select box from back end using c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

i have a select box that is not runat server and i need the values to change according to the count from a database.  so if i have 3 items in the database i would need the count to select 3 in the drop down.  I am using C# on the back end.  All the drop downs associated with this load on pre-render and i can not have post back that is why no runat server with this particular drop down.

and i would need to set the value according to what is in our database but i can not use runat server on the select box
thanks

Comment: set it using javascript

Comment: how about adding a sample of your code

Comment: Also, *why* can you not use `runat="server"`?

Comment: I think you're confusing `runat server` with `autopostback`.  You can runat server without posting back on a selection change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @Smeegs that you're confusing `runat='server'` with `autopostback='true'`. You can runat server without posting back on a selection change. This would enable you to set dropdown value same way as it is done for other dropdowns you have mentioned.

If this is not the case one hack you could do is to add hidden field with `runat` set it on pageload and then on javascript document ready run script that would read value from hidden control and set it to dropdown, however I would highly recommend against it.